# find specific folders from folder on directory

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have this structure:

```
.modules
  .users
    .controllers i want got this files
    .services
  .departament
    .controllers i want got this files
    .services
```

Hello I need to search my src / modules / ** directory and get the controller folder and load files class/functions etc

```
  public importClassesFromDirectories(directories: string[]) {
    let formats = ['.js', '.ts'];
    let rootDir = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'src' : 'build/src';
    let dir = [rootDir + '/modules/**/controllers/**/*.{js,ts}'];
    function loadFileClasses(exported: Array<any> | Object | Function) {}

    return loadFileClasses(dirs, []);
  }
```